# GCP: Terraform:Error: Error setting Cloud Scheduler Job status: googleapi: Error 403: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam, google-cloud-scheduler

Hi I am trying to upgrade google provider for Terraform to 4.40.0 and up on doing this some of the cloud scheduler jobs are failing to deploy with the below error.

`│ Error: Error setting Cloud Scheduler Job status: googleapi: Error 403: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "cloudscheduler.jobs.enable" for the resource "projects/<our_project_name>/locations/<our_location>/jobs/<cloud_scheduler_name>" (or the resource may not exist).`

this was deploying fine with version 4.28.0(which is the version we are using up until now)

Terraform code that creates this resource is:

```
resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "workflow_schedule_datalake_jobs" {
    for_each    = local.workflow_schedule_datalake_jobs
    project     = var.datalake_project_id
    name        = each.value.job_name
    description = each.value.job_description
    schedule    = (var.environment == "dev" || var.environment == "test" ? local.default_dev_schedule : each.value.schedule)
    time_zone   = "Europe/London"
    retry_config {
        retry_count = 1
      }

    http_target {
        http_method = "POST"
        uri         = each.value.url
        oauth_token {
        service_account_email = data.google_service_account.batch_ingestion_service_account.email
      }
    }
}
```

I tried adding admin role for both service account and runtime service account using below.

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "batch_ingest_scheduler_admin" {
    role    = "roles/cloudscheduler.admin"
    member  = "serviceAccount:${data.google_service_account.batch_ingestion_service_account.email}"
    project = var.datalake_project_id
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "batch_ingest_scheduler_admin_default" {
    role    = "roles/cloudscheduler.admin"
    member  = "serviceAccount:service-${var.project_number}@gcp-sa-  cloudscheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    project = var.datalake_project_id
}
```

but still getting the same error.

Just to confirm again only change I was trying to make is upgrading the provider version and no other code changes. Any help is much appreciated.

I tried granted admin access to service account even though this was not granted before. But still getting same error.

Comment: Do you have scheduler API enabled?

Comment: I have a similar issue. My service account has the Owner role and I can create everything fine, just not the Cloud Scheduler job